# Closing all activities

Tags: android, android-activity, exit, kill

I'm searching the web for 2 hours now, but I can't find the answer to my problem.

I want do to a simple action on a button click: close the app, don't save anything, just shut down all the activities and kill/shut down the app.

The app starts up with a splashscreen, followed by a menu. In the menu I want to have a button to exit the app. The user can return to the menu from FirstScreen.

I've read all about starting intents with flags, calling finish(), system.exit(0) and android.os.Killproces. Everytime I try something, the app closes, but it starts up at FirstScreen, that is remebered somehow.

I'm a bit lost now with this problem, while I expected it to be a simple task..;)

I hope anyone can give me an advice for what I should be looking for or give me a suggestion.

Comment: after starting 2nd activity call `finish()` that solves your prob

Comment: Ye that's true, but when the user nomally uses the app, i dont want the activities to be finished during the proces

Comment: hmm ya; but till now i havn't seen any thing like that, ther is a home button if user wants to go out of app :) n also on click of your `exit` button you can invoke HOME keyevent

Comment: Ye true, thats the other side: pressing the home button doesn't complete exits the app either, it starts up at the activity where the user was before exitting. Thats why i wanted this button to shut every thing down. So Android doesn't have some kind of function to kill everything?:s

Comment: One more solution is to start activity for result every time , n if user clicks on exit set a result and propagate same through whole activity stack :)

Comment: Without removing activities from the activity stack, i dont think you can achieve what you want. If you want your app to be able to close(exit) from any activity of the activity then you have to remove previous activites from the stack. If you want your app to be able to close from Homescreen (first screen of the app) only, then you should close the activities while navigating towards Homescreen.

Comment: I guess that indeed is my best option. Every time the user navigates closer to the homescreen, finish the activity where he came from. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you use `startAvtivityForResult` to start `FirstActivity`, then when you finish it, just do something like this:

```
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra("action", "quit");
setResult(RESULT_OK, _result);
finish();
```

Then on your main Activity's `onActivityResult` method, check if the *action* flag is equals to *quit*, and then call `finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Put this code on your exit button.. It will surely work..

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Already tryed this, the app shuts down indeed, but it starts up at FirstScreen if i been there before pressing the shutdown button in menu

Comment: I guess thats what you wanted??

Comment: No, i dont want the user to start up in the middle of the app. I want him start start from zero again

Comment: Ya. this code does that.. but, it will not display the splash screen.. instead of it will jump to the screen which is immediately after splash screen..

Comment: Just remove the app from currently used apps... and run again.. :)